# Android Room Database Create Entity Object without Id

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, android-database

**My entity class:**

```
@Entity(tableName = "student")
data class Student(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    val id: Long,

    val name: String,
    val age: Int,
    val gpa: Double,
    val isSingle: Boolean
)
```

The problem is, since the `id` is auto-generated by the `Room` database - means no matther what I put for the `id` into the constructor it will be overridden anyway, and because it is one of the parameter in the constructor, I have to give the `id` every time like this:

```
val student = Student(0L, "Sam", 27, 3.5, true)
```

How can I avoid making up the `id` so I can just put in the **neccessary** data like this:

```
val student = Student("Sam", 27, 3.5, true)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How can I avoid making up the id

Just set default value to 0 (or null)

```
@Entity(tableName = "student")
data class Student(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    val id: Long = 0, <-- default value (or use null)
```

> id is auto-generated by the Room database - means no matther what I put for the id into the constructor it will be overridden anyway

Not really like that. If you set `id` explicitly then this `id` will be used on insert.

Comment: Doesn't work, tells "Type mismatch" for the first augument.

Comment: Well, you can 1. place `id` parameter as the last constructor's parameter. or 2. use named arguments like `val student = Student(name = "Sam", age = 27, gpa = 3.5, isSingle = true)`

Comment: If you use type Long as in the example, the default value needs to be a Long too, so make it `0L` instead of just `0`

Answer (score 11):

Don't place the id in the constructor:

```
@Entity(tableName = "student")
data class Student(
    val name: String,
    val age: Int,
    val gpa: Double,
    val isSingle: Boolean
) {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    var id: Long? = null
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the auto increment id for your case just in your entity set the type of id to Int and for the id value parameter in your constructor use the null value and this handle the work for you .