# How to ignore some columns during inserting date

Tags: android-room

When you use Android Room auto generated insert method, it pass all values to all columns For example, if you have an entity like below:

```java
@Entity
public class Task {

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    public long id;

    @NonNull
    @ColumnInfo(defaultValue = "Unknown Title")
    public String name;

    @NonNull
    @ColumnInfo(defaultValue = "Does not have any description!")
    public String desc;

    @ColumnInfo(defaultValue = "false")
    public boolean isDone;
}
```

And you try to insert an empty instance of `Task` class by:

```
taskDao.insert(new Task());
```

It will run a query like this:

```
INSERT INTO Task (id, name, desc, isDone) values (null, null, null, 0);
```

that is against of our table structure rules, so we get error:

```
Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: NOT NULL constraint failed: task.name (code 1299 SQLITE_CONSTRAINT_NOTNULL)
```

While if it use this query:

```
INSERT INTO Task DEFAULT VALUES;
```

or

```
INSERT INTO Task (id) VALUES (null);
```

SQLite creates a row with all default values, without any errors.

But to ignore null variables in the insert query for using default valuse?

Comment: why don't you do this: mName="Unknown title"

Comment: I will use the default values but with room it passes null to database, instead of ignoring it

Comment: i don't get what u mean but if u remove the default value from **ColoumnInfo** and pass your default value as a value for the attribute then room will set this default value if the user miss any value u want.

Comment: You right but what you said sets a value that will passed to database, but value of default column in ColumnInfo will use when where are not a passed value like this query `INSERT INTO TABLE task (name) values ("my task");` that ignores id, description and is_done columns

Comment: I update my question completely

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what is written in the [Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/ColumnInfo#defaultValue()):

> The default value you specify here will NOT be used if you simply insert the `Entity` with `@Insert`.

That means there are no simple way but you can do it in some ways:

1. **Assign Variables Values**

Assign what you defined as default values in `@ColumnInfo`, for those variables value, because if you doesn't update those values, the default assignment will be used, as [Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/ColumnInfo#defaultValue()) says:

> If you simply insert the `Entity` with `@Insert` ... any value assigned in Java/Kotlin will be used.

```java
@Entity
public class Task {

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    public long id;

    @NonNull
    @ColumnInfo(defaultValue = "Unknown Title")
    public String name = "Unknown Title";

    @NonNull
    @ColumnInfo(defaultValue = "Does not have any description!")
    public String description = "Does not have any description!";

    @ColumnInfo(defaultValue = "false")
    public boolean isDone; // it doesn't need assignment
                           // boolean values are false as default
}
```

2. **Special Query**

As [Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/ColumnInfo#defaultValue()) recommend:

> Use `@Query` with an `INSERT` statement and skip this column there in order to use this default value.

```java
@Query("INSERT INTO task DEFAULT VALUES")
long insert();
```

or

```java
@Query("INSERT INTO task (id) VALUES (null)")
long insert();
```

As you told in your question.

3. **Simplified Class** [*(ref)*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59834309/3257579)

```java
@Insert(entity = Task.class)
long insert(NewTask task);

@Entity
class NewTask {
    int id = 0;
}
```

it runs

```sql
INSERT INTO task (id) VALUES (null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@Entity
public class Task {
    public String mName = "Unknown Title";
    public String mDescription = "Does not have any description!";
    public boolean mIsDone  = "false";

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)    //must be placed at the end!!
    public long id = 0;
}
```

And create object like this:

```
Task task = new Task()    //all use default values

Task task = new Task(name)    //use default values for other fileds

Task task = new Task(name, description)    //the order matters, otherwise you need to explicitlty specify the filed, like following

Task task = new Task(mIsDone = true, mName = "Sam")
```

---

- Room "deaultValue" is not for entity use:
  https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/ColumnInfo#defaultValue()

Comment: why id must be placed at the end??

Comment: @Mohammad7G https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64517656/android-room-database-create-entity-object-without-id

Comment: @Mohammad7G Does it help?

Comment: about of 1st part of your answer, pay attention to my question, I explained that it passes null. and in part 2 seems that Room doesn't handle my ask directly

Comment: @Mohammad7G You got null because you didn't give the default value to that field man, `columnInfo(defaultValue)` does not work the way you expect, it's for migration use: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/migrating-db-versions#handle-default-values-migrations. Just give it a try.